How to install libmysqlclient21 version 8.0.36 on ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to install libmysqlclient21 with the specific 8.0.36 version on my ubuntu 22.04 server.
Apt repo only has the (higher) version 8.0.40. after uninstalling that one, i tried finding a download for the older version 8.0.36 for my ubuntu dist 22.04. I only found a file named libmysqlclient21_8.0.36-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb on pkgs.
That file does not install though, since it requires many dependencies (libc6, libssl3t64, libste6++,...) on higher versions which are not in the apt repo for my dist. I am afraid that I got a .deb file for ubuntu 24 or so and i dont want to create some patchwork distro.
What is the proper way to install libmysqlclient21 8.0.36 on ubuntu 22.04?
